# How can I use octokit to list open PRs from all repos in my org?

Tags: javascript, github, github-api, octokit-js

I would like to write a script in Javascript to query all open github PRs *in all repos* in my org. I can use this URL to do it in a browser: `https://my.github.server/pulls?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Apr+org%3Amy-org-name`.

But using [octokit](https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v18#pulls-list), I need to supply the name of the repo in which to search. It looks as if the [github API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/pulls?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-pull-requests) also requires it, but like I said, the URL above doesn't supply a repo name and it works just fine.

The documented one also has `/repos` at the beginning, which mine above does not. I can't find the one I'm using anywhere in the github API docs. If I try `octokit.request( 'GET /pulls?q=...' )` as above, I get a 404.

I'm sure there's a way to list the repos and run the above search on each one, but I have dozens of repos, so that's likely to be much slower. Is there a way to do it in one request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to fetch all open PRs across all repositories within an organization in a single request using GitHub's API or Octokit. The Search API can search for PRs but it doesn't support filtering by organization.

You can get a list of all repositories in the organization and use the list of repositories to get all pull requests for each repository.

Example:

```
const { Octokit } = require("@octokit/core");

const octokit = new Octokit({ auth: `your_auth_token` });

async function fetchAllRepos(org) {
    const repos = [];
    let page = 1;
    while (true) {
        const result = await octokit.request('GET /orgs/{org}/repos', {
            org: org,
            type: 'public',
            per_page: 100,
            page: page
        });

        if (result.data.length === 0) break;
        repos.push(...result.data);
        page++;
    }
    return repos;
}

async function fetchAllPRs(org) {
    const repos = await fetchAllRepos(org);

    const prPromises = repos.map(repo =>
        octokit.request('GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/pulls', {
            owner: org,
            repo: repo.name,
            state: 'open'
        })
    );

    const prResults = await Promise.all(prPromises);
    const prs = prResults.flatMap(result => result.data);
    return prs;
}

fetchAllPRs('my-org-name')
    .then(prs => console.log(prs))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Not sure how slow this will be in your case. I hope this helps anyway.

Comment: This is perfect. Turns out doing it one repo at a time is plenty fast enough. I didn't mention this but I need to filter based on labels as well, and I didn't see a parameter for that, but just doing that in my Javascript code is also fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It does support filtering by org. Use:

```js
await octokit.request("GET /search/issues", {
    q: `is:pr is:open org:ORGANIZATION`,
});
```